# SQL query to update records with the same filename

Tags: mysql, sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I wanted to update filename from documents records that has duplicates or same filename based on employeeId. Thank you. In order to make it unique I want to add prefix to the filename on update.

#code qquery

```
SELECT id, filename, employeeId, COUNT(filename) FROM documents GROUP BY filename
      HAVING COUNT(filename) > 1;
```

#result
[image]

#table

[image]

#code for updating

```
const documents = await sequelizeClient.query(
        `SELECT id, filename, employeeId, COUNT(filename) FROM ${EmployeeDocumentsModel.tableName} GROUP BY filename
      HAVING COUNT(filename) > 1;`,
        { type: QueryTypes.SELECT },
      );

      const promises = [];
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
      for (let i = 0; i < documents.length; i++) {
        const prefix = Date.now().toString();
        const fileParts = documents[i].filename.split('.');
        const finalname = `${fileParts[0]}-${prefix}.${fileParts[1]}`;
        promises.push(queryInterface.sequelize.query(`UPDATE documents SET filename='${finalname}' WHERE employeeID=${documents[i].employeeId};`));
      }
      await Promise.all(promises);
```

Comment: This really is the same as your previous question...

Comment: @GMB it has not been answered Sir

Comment: @GMB , do you have some idea with this one Sir ?